# Powershell How to Concatenate Multiple Results

Tags: sql-server, powershell, cluster-computing

From a list of servers (`Servers.txt`), I'm getting AG and Listener name for each of them.

For being able to get `-ClusterParameter HostRecordTTL, RegisterAllProvidersIP` I need to concatenate AG_Name+Listener_Name:
Ex.: `Get-ClusterResource -cluster "SERVER001" -name "AGNAME001_ISTENER001" | Get-ClusterParameter HostRecordTTL,RegisterAllProvidersIP`

The issue is when I have more than 01 AG/Listener for the same server.
How can I concatenate AG + Listener for each line returned for same Server?

Previously I was using TOP 1, but it only got the first Line returned and some servers I got more than 04 AGs/Listeners.

```
$output = foreach ($cluster in GC "D:\Servers_List.txt")
{
    $AGName =  invoke-sqlcmd -Serverinstance $cluster -query "select top 1 left(name,25) as ' ' from sys.availability_groups order by 1" 
    $LNName =  invoke-sqlcmd -Serverinstance $cluster -query "select top 1 left(dns_name,25) ' ' from sys.availability_group_listeners order by 1" 
    $NetworkName = "$($AGName." ")_$($LNName." ")" 
    Get-ClusterResource -cluster $cluster -name $NetworkName | Get-ClusterParameter HostRecordTTL,RegisterAllProvidersIP 
} 
$output | Export-Csv 'D:\RAPIPHRTTL.csv' -NoType
```

Answer (score 0):

try Something like this:

```
$output = foreach ($cluster in GC "D:\Servers_List.txt")
{
    #modify your querys like necessary + rename columns
    $AGNames =  invoke-sqlcmd -Serverinstance $cluster -query "select left(name,25) as AG from sys.availability_groups order by 1" 
    $LNNames =  invoke-sqlcmd -Serverinstance $cluster -query "select left(dns_name,25) as LN from sys.availability_group_listeners order by 1" 

    #build list combination    
    $NetworkNames=$AGNames | foreach{$AG=$_.AG; $LNNames | foreach{"{0}_{1}" -f $AG, $_.LN}    }

    #use list combination for get cluster ressources   
    $NetworkNames | foreach{
    Get-ClusterResource -cluster $cluster -name $_ | Get-ClusterParameter HostRecordTTL,RegisterAllProvidersIP 
    }

} 
$output | Export-Csv 'D:\RAPIPHRTTL.csv' -NoType
```

Answer (score 0):

Better solution, build into your query (only one query is better for performance i think)

```
$output = foreach ($cluster in GC "D:\Servers_List.txt")
{
    #only one query calculate all combinations and build string name ressources
    $NetworkNames =  invoke-sqlcmd -Serverinstance $cluster -query "select left(f1.name,25) + '_' + left(f2.dns_name,25) as AGLN from sys.availability_groups f1 cross join sys.availability_group_listeners f2 " 

    $NetworkNames | foreach{
    Get-ClusterResource -cluster $cluster -name $_.AGLN | Get-ClusterParameter HostRecordTTL,RegisterAllProvidersIP 
    }

} 
$output | Export-Csv 'D:\RAPIPHRTTL.csv' -NoType
```

NB: you can simplify your code like this:

```
$Query="select left(f1.name,25) + '_' + left(f2.dns_name,25) as AGLN from sys.availability_groups f1 cross join sys.availability_group_listeners f2 "

GC "D:\Servers_List.txt" | foreach{
    $cluster=$_
    invoke-sqlcmd -Serverinstance $cluster -query $Query | foreach{
    Get-ClusterResource -cluster $cluster -name $_.AGLN | Get-ClusterParameter HostRecordTTL,RegisterAllProvidersIP
    }

} | Export-Csv 'D:\RAPIPHRTTL.csv' -NoType
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Esperento57!